# Image shuffling with Arnold's cat map

Tags: algorithm, vba, visual-studio, security, math

I'm working on implementing 2D Arnold's cat map of N x M images. The problem is that I can't get back the original pixel's values (i.e Arnold cat map inverse not working). Any solution from any freelancer will be paid for. I wrote the VB 6.0 code according to 2D Arnold's cat map equations fro shuffling and inverse.

```
Private Sub Cipher()
 Dim Hm As Integer, i As Integer, x As Integer
 Dim Wm As Integer, j As Integer, y As Integer
Wm = Wid - 1: Hm = Hgt - 1
    pic1.ScaleMode = vbPixels
    pic1.ScaleWidth = Wid
    pic1.ScaleHeight = Hgt

Dim pp As Double, qq As Double
Dim nn As Integer, k As Integer
Dim xnn As Double, ynn As Double

pp = 2: qq = 5
nn = 1

For k = 1 To nn
For y = 0 To Hm
For x = 0 To Wm

 '''''''''''' arnold cat map''''''''''''''''''
xnn = x + pp * y
ynn = qq * x + (pp * qq + 1) * y

 xnn = xnn Mod Wm
 ynn = ynn Mod Hm

 Red(xnn, ynn) = Red(x, y)
 Grn(xnn, ynn) = Grn(x, y)
 Blu(xnn, ynn) = Blu(x, y)
    Next x: Next y
'''''''''''' end of shfulling
For y = 0 To Hm: For x = 0 To Wm
pic1.PSet (x, y), RGB(Red(x, y), Grn(x, y), Blu(x, y))
Next x: Next y
pic1.Refresh
Next k
End Sub
```

This is the code for inverse of Arnold cat map:

Private Sub DeCipher()

```
 Dim Hm As Integer, i As Integer, x As Integer
 Dim Wm As Integer, j As Integer, y As Integer
Wm = Wid - 1: Hm = Hgt - 1

pic2.ScaleWidth = Wid
pic2.ScaleHeight = Hgt


Dim pp As Double, qq As Double
Dim nn As Integer, k As Integer
Dim xnn As Double, ynn As Double


pp = 2: qq = 5
nn = 1

For k = 1 To nn 'no. of iterations

For y = 0 To Hm
For x = 0 To Wm

 '''''''''''' Inverse of Arnold Cat map''''''''''''''''''
 xnn = Abs((x * ((pp * qq) + 1)) + (-pp * y))
 ynn = Abs((-qq * x) + y)

 xnn = xnn Mod Wm
 ynn = ynn Mod Hm
 '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Red(xnn, ynn) = Red(x, y)
 Grn(xnn, ynn) = Grn(x, y)
 Blu(xnn, ynn) = Blu(x, y)
    Next x: Next y
'''''''''''' end of shuffling
Next k

For y = 0 To Hm: For x = 0 To Wm
pic2.PSet (x, y), RGB(Red(x, y), Grn(x, y), Blu(x, y))

Next x: Next y
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The task is impossible since you overwrite pixels while encoding. Overwritten information is erased and can not be reconstructed. If you were to change the encoding code to have different color arrays for original end encoded image,

```
CodeRed(xnn, ynn) = OrigRed(x, y)
CodeGrn(xnn, ynn) = OrigGrn(x, y)
CodeBlu(xnn, ynn) = OrigBlu(x, y)
```

then you could use the same index computation as in the forward loop, only copying backward,

```
For k = 1 To nn
For y = 0 To Hm
For x = 0 To Wm

   '''''''''''' arnold cat map''''''''''''''''''
  xnn = x + pp * y
  ynn = qq * x + (pp * qq + 1) * y

  xnn = xnn Mod Wm
  ynn = ynn Mod Hm

  OrigRed(x, y) = CodeRed(xnn, ynn)
  OrigGrn(x, y) = CodeGrn(xnn, ynn)
  OrigBlu(x, y) = CodeBlu(xnn, ynn)

Next x: Next y
```

Comment: I did that but it does not worked for me. I still can not perform the inverse equation of Arnold's cat map.